# Raise Error, dispose object and re-create it

Tags: c#, .net, events

Let's assume we have the following two classes, How can we listen for Errors and if any error occurred, recreate the singleton? I have put together the following code, but would like to know if there is a pattern for safely raise error, dispose object and recreate it automatically?

`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyFirstClass.Instance.SayHello();
    }
}
class MySecondClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public void SayHelloFromSecondClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Say Hello From Second Class");
    }
    public MySecondClass(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}

public sealed class MyFirstClass
{
    private static readonly MyFirstClass instance = new MyFirstClass();
    private static MySecondClass msc;

    public event EventHandler ErrorOccuredEvent;

    private MyFirstClass() { }

    public static MyFirstClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            msc = new MySecondClass(id: 1);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World...");

    }

    static void ErrorOccured(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Oops");
        msc = null;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        GC.Collect();
        msc = new MySecondClass(id: 2);


    }
}
```

`

Comment: What is the relation of `msc` to `instance`? Like this the code seems not to make a lot of sense. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? What are your real objects?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks, I have two objectives: 1) I want the 'EntryClass' to be a singleton that ONLY creates a single instance of `ServiceClass` which is not a singleton, now the question here is whether to remove '`EntryClass` and make the `ServiceClass` a Singleton itself? 2) I want the "EntryClass" to listen for errors, if occurred, automatically dispose `ServiceClass` and re-create it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, `MyFirstClass` (which is a singleton) is a kind of wrapper around `MySecondClass` that turns `MySecondClass` into a singleton as well.

Let's call `MyFirstClass`: `Wrapper`

Let's call `MySecondClass`: `Service`

If the clients always consume the `Service` through the single instance of `Wrapper`, then re-creating a `Wrapper` will not help, because the clients might keep a reference to `Wapper`. Re-creating `Service` can help if the clients don't see it and cannot keep a reference to it. Therefore they must consume the service indirectly.

It's easiest to achieve this through an interface:

```
public interface IHelloService
{
    void SayHello();
}

public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}

public class HelloServiceWrapper : IHelloService
{
    public static readonly IHelloService Instance = new HelloServiceWrapper();

    private HelloServiceWrapper () {}

    private IHelloService _service;

    public void SayHello()
    {
        EnsureServiceAvailable();
        _service.SayHello(); 
    }

    private void EnsureServiceAvailable()
    {
        if(_service == null) {
            _service = new HelloService();
        }
    }

    private void HandleError()
    {
        _service = null;
    }
}
```

But if the error happens when the client is using the service ...

```
HelloServiceWrapper.Instace.SayHello();
```

... this call might fail.

You would have to re-create the service instantly in order to make succeed the client's call (assuming that re-creating the service will solve the problem and that the error will not occur again immediately):

```
public void SayHello()
{
    try {
        _service.SayHello();
    } catch {
        _service = new HelloService();
        _service.SayHello();
    }
}
```

---

Note: Disposing the service invalidates the object and makes any reference a client has to it invalid. But re-creating a new one does not give the client a new reference! You would need to have a reference to the clients reference in order to be able to give the client a new instance.